# How to change slide direction for resetToPage?

Tags: onsen-ui

I am building one app in which there are stack of multiple pages 
whenever I want to go to 1st page I am using resetToPage.

```
navigator.resetToPage("page2.html", { animation: "slide" }):
```

Default it is taking right to left transition I need exactly revers of this similar to popPage transition.

I there way to achieve it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find some information about this here: http://onsen.io/guide/overview.html#Transitionanimation

Basically, you can create a new animator and define it as you need. This is the basic example in OnsenUI repository: https://github.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/blob/1.3.14/framework/views/simpleSlideTransitionAnimator.js

As you can see there, two functions are defined: push and pop animations. `resetToPage()` uses the "push" animation like `pushPage()` does, not like `popPage()`. However, if you just want to invert that, you can create a new animator and define its "push" function exactly the same as the previous "pop" function. You have a quick example here:

http://codepen.io/frankdiox/pen/azQMZE

If you change the parameters of the transform functions you will get a different behavior, so you can adapt it as you want. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you do `navigator.popPage({animation: "slide"})`, then the animation is reversed.

So, before you do that, you just have to insert a page in the stack before your current page.

If you want to simulate `resetToPage`, you must destroy previous pages by yourself too.

```
var pageStack = navigator.getPages();
for(var len = pageStack.length - 2, i = len ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
   pageStack[i].destroy();
}
navigator.insertPage( 0, "page2.html", { animation: "slide" } );
navigator.popPage({animation: "slide"});
```